# How can I use chronicle queue for non-persisted IPC?

Tags: ipc, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I don't need any persistence for local IPC. Can I somehow use chronicle queue with the memory of a fixed size or fixed-size file as buffer in order not to have to store processed messages? Or that you can advise me to such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have plans to implement this in Chronicle v4 in the next few weeks.

We suggest using the stored messages for testing. Also an open ended queue means the producer does need to stop for a slow consumer.

An alternative is to use Aeron which uses shared memory for IPC to act as a fixed size buffer.

Comment: Was this functionality added?  If so, where can I find it?